# My anchor tags links are not working in IOS devices for nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

When I'm trying to use normal anchor tags or Links inside the IOS devices it simply doesn't route to specific pages.
tried with various options that nextjs link docs says and tested it with normal anchor tags but it does not work out in my case

```
<Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
              {navList?.map((data, index) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <Link
                      key={data.id}
                      onMouseOver={() => {
                        if (data.multi_link) {
                          setNavLink(true);
                        } else {
                          handleClose();
                        }
                      }}
                      onMouseLeave={() => {
                        setNavLink(false);
                      }}
                      className={`${
                        currentRoute === data?.href
                          ? "activeNav font-bold mx-2 p-3 sm:!p-2  lg:text-[#fff]  text-[#043b72] hover:text-[#f58220] text-[16px] leading-[26px]"
                          : "font-bold mx-2 p-3 sm:!p-2 lg:text-[#fff] text-[#043b72] hover:text-[#f58220] text-[16px] leading-[26px]"
                      } `}
                      style={
                        navLink && data?.multi_link && window.innerWidth <= 767
                          ? { marginBottom: "200px" }
                          : { marginBottom: "0" }
                      }
                      href={data?.href && data?.href}
                      passHref
                    >
                      {data?.label}
                      {data.multi_link && navLink && (
                        <div
                          onMouseLeave={() => {
                            setNavLink(false);
                          }}
                          className="bg-[#f58220] m-1 !font-normal text-[#ffffff]  w-48 absolute z-20"
                        >
                          {regulatoryLinks.map((x) => {
                            return (
                              <p
                                onClick={(e) => {
                                  e.preventDefault();
                                  setShow(false);
                                  setNavLink(false);
                                }}
                                key={x.id}
                                className="p-2 hover:text-[#ffffff]"
                              >
                                <Link href={x.href}>{x.label}</Link>
                              </p>
                            );
                          })}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Link>
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </Nav>
```